# Handling an empty SOAP message

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

Trying to handle an empty SOAP message with Spring Web Services but failing.

So, I have a request to provide an endpoint for a sort of a PING method. Basically the SOAP messages I can handle look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:def="http://www.something.com/edf/services/defaultservice">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <def:ServiceReqType>
            <transactionId>1111</transactionId>
            <subscriberId>2222</subscriberId>
        </def:ServiceReqType>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and that I can handle with an endpoint that is handling `ServiceReqType`.

But the PING looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

That I can't handle, Spring logs a `Can't handle [SaajSoapMessage]`.

What I need to return is the exactly same message.

I understand there that there is a type/class missing that I would provide to `@PayloadRoot`.

So I am wondering what would an endpoint specification be for this empty bodied request?

Just for reference here is my endpoint for handling the `ServiceReqType`:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_EDF, localPart = "ServiceReqType")
@ResponsePayload
public ServiceRespType serviceResponse(@RequestPayload ServiceReqType request) {
        LOGGER.debug("-----> ServiceReqType:{}", request);
        return reqProcessor.process(request);
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

So I tried with implementing the interceptor in the following way:

```
public class CustomEndpointInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomEndpointInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("---> Message context: {}", messageContext.toString());
        LOGGER.info("---> Message endpoint: {}", endpoint.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("handleResponse");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("handleFault");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("afterCompletion");
    }
}
```

and then in the `WebServiceConfiguration` class I added this:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    interceptors.add(new CustomEndpointInterceptor());
    super.addInterceptors(interceptors);
}
```

But it still does not work. What I get is that the interceptor is called when SOAP message has a BODY but when it is sent a `Ping` that is BODYless then I get again the same error message and interceptor is not called. So it seems I must find an interceptor that is further up the chain...

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is how WSDL file looks like for this Ping...

```
<message name="PingRequest"/>

<message name="PingResponse"/>
```

There is nothing as a part inside of these...

For comparison this is how `ServiceReqType` looks:

```
<message name="ServiceReqType">
  <part name="body" element="tns:ServiceReqTypeDefinition"/>
</message>
```

and then the `ServiceReqTypeDefinition` is defined in an accompanying `xsd` file.

**UPDATE 3:**

So, found the reason why interceptors won't work on this type of message :-/

Below code is from `MessageDispatcher` line 234.

```
// No triggering of interceptors if no endpoint is found
if (endpointNotFoundLogger.isWarnEnabled()) {
  endpointNotFoundLogger.warn("No endpoint mapping found for [" + messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
}
throw ex;
```

So it's on purpose, now I need to find how to handle these incomplete or incorrect SOAP messages... any ideas because rewriting `Dispatcher` doesn't feel like the right way.

**UPDATE 4**

So, I managed to intercept the payload, the one that is invalid, by extending `AbstractEndpointMapping` class and then overriding `getInternalEndpoint` gives me the possibility to evaluate the message and see if it is this empty Ping request I have been trying to process.

I think this would all be easily solved if I knew how to define a `defaultEndpoint` because I see that in case SOAP message is not recognised, so no endpoint mapping is found, this `defaultEndpoint` is used to handle that message.

I noticed that when working with XML specification of `Beans` then there is a property to define the endpoint as a default one, but how to do it when using annotations?

Another way is to just create an endpoint and then return it from `getInternalEndpoint` so spring can handle processing, I guess, but I don't know yet how to create an endpoint object... working on that now.

p.s. [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.4.7.RELEASE/reference/#server-endpoint-mapping) documentation mentions `defaultEndpoint` but not how to set it up in a non XML defining Bean way.

Comment: Why not define a `Ping` method?

Comment: @Olivier how would I do that? The think is that as far as I can understand, BODY is non existent in `Ping` and as such I am not sure I can define a Payload that will match void? I mean I tried something along those lines but didn't work.
I am looking into implementing some kind of interceptor that will read the whole SOAP message and then if body is empty will take care of handling that, otherwise will pass it on to dispatcher.

Comment: What I meant is that the request body should not be empty (which is most likely not a valid SOAP request), but should instead call a specific method (`Ping` or whatever name you prefer). If the goal is to test that the service is operational, that's all you need.

Comment: I don't control the request coming in, I just got the specification and I am not sure how they have set it up since WSDL I got has `Ping` in it as I provided it here. And When I generate `XSD` files from it and use them to build POJOs there is no way the standard Spring Web Services can handle the `Ping` since it's empty.

Comment: I don't know anything about Java, Spring or Spring Web Services. Just some thoughts here. If you as server get a SOAP message with an empty body, why not just send back a SOAPFault ? If you test your own webservice, can you handle a valid `Ping` request?

Comment: @Piemol I tried that, but SOAPFault is not even triggered since it's not perceived as a SOAP error but that there is no endpoint to handle it. The weird issue is that all SOAP validators show this as valid SOAP. I believe I need to create a custom MessageDispatcher that handles this type of payload.

Comment: @Dusko SOAPFaults may also be triggered on invalid payloads. E.g. the completely misssing payload; invalid `ping` message; other server errors. Maybe this is of any help for you? https://www.javaspringclub.com/spring-soap-web-services-add-soap-fault-exception-handling-part-iii/

Comment: @Piemol that is the tutorial I was following but still this payload is not intercepted. I will go over it again in case I missed something, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end I had to create a custom exception handler. Something like this:

```
public class CustomEndpointNotFoundException extends Exception {
    public CustomEndpointNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

then:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class NoEndpointFoundEndpointMapping implements EndpointMapping {
    @Override
    public EndpointInvocationChain getEndpoint(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
        throw new CustomEndpointNotFoundException("");
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
@Component
public class CustomEndpointExceptionResolver implements EndpointExceptionResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean resolveException(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) {
        if (messageIsPing()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So basically I am handling it as an error. It's not really ideal solution IMHO, I will still see if I can intercept the endpoint resolution, or define a default endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, I needed a way to dump the whole SOAP message (not just the body), to analyze an existing implementation.